# InDesign CS5 / Script: Can I convert TIFF and PNG images to `black and white`?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have a script that scans a document for all image types, converts them all to black and white, and then exports the black and white images to a new folder.

---

It seems as if InDesign will export these image file-formats:  `JPEG, TIFF, and PNG` (it does **not** export GIF files).

However, it seems that InDesign doesn't have the `ColorSpace.GRAY` or `ColorSpaceEnum.GRAY` properties for TIFF and PNG files (it **does** have this property for JPEG files, though).

---

- So, is there a way to convert TIFF and PNG files to black and white
  in InDesign's Extendscript?
- If there is **not**, what would be the reasoning for not providing
  black and white conversion for these file types?

---

Here is my code, that as of now exports only black and white JPEG files:

```
var document = app.activeDocument;
var newFolder = createFolder(document); // if subdirectory DNE, create this folder with the function below

saveAllImages(document, newFolder); // with the function below



function createFolder(doc)
{
    try
    {
      /*
         * type-casting the filePath property (of type object) into a String type;
         * must be a String type to concatenate with the subdirectory variable (also of type String)
         */
        var docPath = String(doc.filePath);
        var subdirectory = "/BLACK AND WHITE IMAGES";
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
        exit();
    }

    var imagesFolder = docPath + subdirectory; // concatenating the two variables
    if(!Folder(imagesFolder).exists)
    {
        Folder(imagesFolder).create();
    }

    return imagesFolder; // for instantiation outside of this function

} // end of function createFolder



function saveAllImages(doc, folder)
{
    var imgs = doc.allGraphics;
    var fileName = "";
    var img = "";
    var imgType = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    {
        if(imgs[i].itemLink != null)
        {
            fileName = imgs[i].itemLink.name;
            img = new File(folder + "/" + fileName); // each image instantiated here
            imgType = imgs[i].imageTypeName; // image type is determined here (.tif, .jpg, .png, etc..)

            alert("This is a " + imgType + " file.");

            /*
                * array for image options, instantiated from the function below;
                * options[0] is the "MAXIMUM" image quality property, &
                * options[1] is the "GRAY" image conversion property;
                */
            var options = convertToBlackAndWhite(imgType);

            // each image exported to the new folder here, by file type
            switch(imgType)
            {
                case "GIF":
                    alert("This script cannot convert and export the GIF file:\n\t" + fileName + " !");
                    break;

                case "TIFF":

            case "EPS":

                case "JPG":
                    options[0]; // maximum image quality
                    options[1]; // black & white conversion

                    imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, img, false);
                    break;

                case "PNG":
                    options[0]; // maximum image quality
                    options[1]; // black & white conversion

                    imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.PNG_TYPE, img, false);
                    break;

                default:
                    alert("\tUnlisted image type: " + imgType + "!\nAdd this type to the switch statement.");
                    break;
            } // end of switch statement

        } // end of if statement
    } // end of for loop

} // end of function saveAllImages



        function convertToBlackAndWhite(fileType)
        {
            // array for image-quality and color-conversion values
            var settings = [];

            // each image exported to the new folder here, by file type
            switch(fileType)
            {
                case "TIFF":

                case "PNG":

            case "EPS":

                case "JPG":
                    settings[0] = "app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM"; // maximum image quality
                    settings[1] = "app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegColorSpace = JpegColorSpaceEnum.GRAY"; // black & white conversion
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            } // end of switch statement

            return settings; // for instantiation outside of this function

        } // end of function convertToBlackAndWhite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to convert TIFF and PNG files to black and white in
>   InDesign's Extendscript?

Not that I am aware of.

> If there is not, what would be the reasoning for not providing black and white conversion for these file types?

He he only God knows :D

Given your expectations, I would rather delegate these image operations to Photoshop where you can use any formats you want, any settings you want. You can either use a BridgeTalk object or have a hotfolder that will run Ps ( applescript for ex ).
Or you could use a doScript to call applescript or visualbasic depending on your os and have them run some conversion tool you might have.

Good luck.

Loic

PS: See this tool also. Maybe it has some API you can call with JS
http://www.rorohiko.com/wordpress/indesign-downloads/color2gray/

Comment: Hmm ok, well as you are saying formatting the files in Photoshop might be more desirable anyway, so I am looking into using the `BridgeTalk` object (I have found a good reference here:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/3334670#3334670). Thanks @Loic! I will post my code when I have figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

So, though I have been working on a version of this code that uses `BridgeTalk`, I discovered recently that any formatting that is applied to JPEG's can be applied to .BMP's, .TIF's, .EPS's, and .PNG's by *programmatically* renaming the file extension afterwards to the desired format.

However, .PDF's **cannot** be coerced into different file formats, because they are then incorrectly formatted and corrupted.

Here is my working code, which is pretty similar to the above code, with a few modifications:

```
var document = app.activeDocument;
var newFolder = createFolder(document); // if subdirectory images DNE, create this folder with the function below

saveAllImages(document, newFolder); // with the function below

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function createFolder(doc)
{
    try
    {
      /*
         * type-casting the filePath property (of type object) into a String type;
         * must be a String type to concatenate with the subdirectory variable (also of type String)
         */
        var docPath = String(doc.filePath);
        var subdirectory = "/BLACK AND WHITE IMAGES";
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
        exit();
    }

    var imagesFolder = docPath + subdirectory; // concatenating the two variables
    if(!Folder(imagesFolder).exists)
    {
        Folder(imagesFolder).create();
    }

    return imagesFolder; // for instantiation outside of this function

} // end of function createFolder

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function saveAllImages(doc, folder)
{
    var imgs = doc.allGraphics;
    var fileName = "";
    var img = "";
    var imgType = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    {
        if(imgs[i].itemLink != null)
        {
            fileName = imgs[i].itemLink.name;
            var str = fileName.substr(0, fileName.length - 4) + ".tif"; // converting all file types to .TIF
            img = new File(folder + "/" + str); // each image instantiated here
            imgType = imgs[i].imageTypeName; // image type is determined here (.tif, .jpg, .png, etc..)

            //alert("The file \"" + fileName + "\"\n\tis a " + imgType + " file.");

            /*
                * array for image options, instantiated from the function below;
                * options[0] is the "MAXIMUM" image quality property, &
                * options[1] is the "GRAY" image conversion property;
                */
            var options = convertToBlackAndWhite(imgType);

            // each image exported to the new folder here, by file type
            switch(imgType)
            {
                case "GIF":
                    alert("This script cannot convert and export the GIF file:\n\t" + fileName + " !");
                    break;

                case "Adobe PDF":
                    // PDF file type does not have the maximum image quality property
                    options[1]; // black & white conversion

                    imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.PDF_TYPE, img, false);
                    break;

                case "EPS":
                    // PDF file type does not have the maximum image quality property
                    options[1]; // black & white conversion

                    imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.EPS_TYPE, img, false);
                    break;

                case "Windows Bitmap":
                case "PNG":
                case "TIFF":
                case "JPEG":
                    options[0]; // maximum image quality
                    options[1]; // black & white conversion

                    imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, img, false);
                    break;

                default:
                    alert("\tUnlisted image type: " + imgType + "!\nAdd this type to the switch statement.");
                    break;
            } // end of switch statement

            replaceWithNewImage(doc, fileName, img); // with the function below

        } // end of if statement
    } // end of for loop

} // end of function saveAllImages

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        function convertToBlackAndWhite(fileType)
        {
            // array for image-quality and color-conversion values
            var settings = [];

            // each image exported to the new folder here, by file type
            switch(fileType)
            {
                case "Adobe PDF":
                    settings[0] = ""; // PDF file type does not have the maximum image quality property
                    settings[1] = "app.pdfExportPreferences.pdfColorSpace = PDFColorSpace.GRAY"; // black & white conversion
                    break;

                case "EPS":
                    settings[0] = ""; // EPS file type does not have the maximum image quality property
                    settings[1] = "app.epsExportPreferences.epsColorSpace = EPSColorSpace.GRAY"; // black & white conversion
                    break;

                case "Windows Bitmap":
                case "PNG":
                case "TIFF":
                case "JPEG":
                    settings[0] = "app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM"; // maximum image quality
                    settings[1] = "app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegColorSpace = JpegColorSpaceEnum.GRAY"; // black & white conversion
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            } // end of switch statement

            return settings; // for instantiation outside of this function

        } // end of function convertToBlackAndWhite
```

Though I did not use `BridgeTalk`, I am still looking into this and have found a good reference here:  http://www.kasyan.ho.com.ua/convert_cmyk-rgb_images_to_grayscale.html.

And for ideas on *not* overwriting the original images:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/4292613#4292613.